# What language is google using for it's deep learning AI program?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am just getting into AI and algorithms and wanted to know which programming language google is using in it's deep learning program .By any chance is it Python?

Answer (score -1):

I strongly believe most of their AI based applications runs on Python, because you always choose tools you know and Python is quite popular and effective, having lots of already implemented tools to help you with the subject.

But remember, you can implement any algorithm in any language, even in [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).

Comment: Thanks ! I even got to know about the  new language you mentioned!

Comment: No don't do that :D it was just an example.

Comment: Don't worry I got that one when I found the syntax of it! Well it would take another AI to write an AI code in Whitespace !!